# Kubectl port-forward has no effect

Tags: kubernetes, redis, kubectl, portforwarding, redis-cli

I'm trying to forward my redis pod to my local redis client. I checked pods, services, replica sets, deployments.

The command that I'm running on my cluster:

`$ kubectl port-forward svc/redis 7000:6379`

The response of it:

```
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:7000 -> 6379
Forwarding from [::1]:7000 -> 6379
```

Even though, I can not connect from my terminal with `$ redis-cli -p 7000`.

It turns me an error and nothing happens in Kubernetes:

```
Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:7000: Connection refused
not connected>
```

Note: I've also tried `--address` option, `sudo`, different ports and to forward with `pod/<pod_name>`.

Is there anything that I missed?

Comment: check the lable of deployment and service or stateful sets, if possible please share it also.

Comment: replicaset.apps/redis-6767b4465, deployment.apps/redis, service/redis, pod/redis-6767b4465-qx6w2. There is no stateful set about redis. @HarshManvar

Comment: Try another ports maybe it's block by firewall or it has been already occupied by other apps.

Comment: I've tried 6378, 6379, 6380 and also automatically generated ports. @MahdiYusefi

Comment: Does Redis allow connection from the IP outside? What is the bind value in redis.conf?